# Предупреждение при скачивании файла zip

Tags: php, html, zip

Мне нужно создать zip файл и скачать его при загрузке файла Google Chrome предупреждает что файл может быть вредоносным. Как можно это исправить ?
Код

```
$zip_file = public_path().'/storage/file.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ( $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    exit("message");
    }
$zip->addFromString(basename('file.cs'),$plugin);
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();

header("Cache-Control: public");
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($zip_file)."\"");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile($zip_file);
unlink($zip_file);
exit();
```

Comment: Написать в гугл. Они как-то анализируют содержимое.

Comment: Ясно кароче у меня было 2 домена 1 добавлен на гугл 2 рой новый вот если качивать через тот который добавлен все ок) если через 2 рой то вирус.

Comment: Не по проблеме, но у вас плохой код. Он плох тем, что используется `$zip_file = public_path().'/storage/file.zip';`. А что если два человека одновременно решат скачать? Используйте [tempnam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). А по проблеме - слишком много переменных. Напишите в саппорт, потом поделитесь.

Comment: У меня открыт рут на скачивание прежде чем приступать к созданию файла идет проверка. Да проблема в том что гугл должен проиндексировать мой сайт тогда он дает доступ у меня 2 URL на один и тотже сайт 1 работает 2 рой показывает вирусный файл.

Answer (score 0):

PHP и программирование тут вообще ни при чем. Гугл анализирует файл, а не способ которым он отдается. А может и не анализирует, а просто пишет, чтобы потроллить.

Вообще он очень часто предупреждает, что файл может быть вредоносным. А может у тебя просто в архиве троян.